# <script> tags not executing in ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am having the same problem as faced by many that the script tags are not executed in the jquery ajax response and i already tried the solutions with the 'eval()' method and similar but none is working.Is there any other way to accomplish this.
i am sending a ajax request to a file cart.php from home.php

HOME.php

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"cart.php?action=inc&id="+id+"&value="+myvalue+"&linecost="+linecost,
    cache:false,

    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
```

i am actually converting a php array to a javascript array inside cart.php file like this:

CART.php:

```
 processing code here...

<?php    
$res=array($val,$cost,$total);
    foreach ($res as $a) {
    $string .= "\"" . $a . "\", ";
    $final = substr($string, 0 ,(strlen($string) - 2));
    }
?>
<script>var j = new Array(<?php echo $final; ?>);</script>
```

Returned data at home.php inside data variable:

```
<script>var j = new Array("4", "2928", "6708");</script>
```

Now i just want the elements of this array but it is returning the whole line at the calling file inside the 'success' function..how do i extract the values at the calling file?Any help?

Comment: Please clarify "not working" you mentioned in previous attempts, what's "returned data", returned by what? and the "calling file"-part, what is a calling file? also how are jQuery and ajax related to that problem? Also why isn't php relevant to the problem?

Comment: @Winchestro please refer the edited question.

Comment: Sure that you have included jQuery correctly? Sure that you wrap your jQuery with `$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });` or `jQuery(function($) { /* ... */ });`? **what says the javacript console**?

Comment: Why don't you return the data as JSON?

Comment: @Adrian on excution of alert(data),it alerts
<script>var j = new Array("4", "2928", "6708");</script>
i.e.along with the <script> tags.

Comment: @MaxMeijer can you direct me to a tutorial for the same as i have never used json before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use JSON. Instead of returning the script, you can use [json_encode](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
 echo json_encode($final);
```

Then to convert the JSON back to an array you can do in JS:

```
 var result=JSON.parse(data);
```

`result` is now a normal JS array containing the same data as in `$final`.

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question. Your answer is good. I didn't know about the json_encode method as I don't know php.